# Captive portal Redirect to Chrome

Tags: android, html, forms

I am Trying to redirect public wifi login page to chrome Browser (using html mikrotik router) and redirect successfully and authenticate properly.

But

We have one issue when we click on sign in to log in public wifi then we have to need one more click on CONTINUE ANYWAY VIA BROWSER" then redirect successfully to chrome browser.

So I have need to not click on  ''CONTINUE ANYWAY VIA BROWSER'' and redirect to chrome directly its possible.

(When I click sign in wifi network below page open :-

The network that you are trying to join is requesting to open another application. For example, the login page may require a specific application for authentication CONTINUE ANYWAY VIA BROWSER)

Need help to paid wifi authentication